# Materialize css checkbox not working in rails app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, checkbox, rubygems, materialize

I'm trying to add checkboxes to a form for users to select the workshops that they want but I cannot make the checkboxes appear. I'm using Materialize Css gem with rails.

My form is the next:

```
<div class="row">
  <% workshops = Workshop.all.order("date") %>
  <% workshops.each do |workshop| %>
    <div class=" col m4 s6">
      <%= f.label "#{workshop.name} \n\r #{workshop.date}", for:"workshop_id", id:"workshop_id" %>
      <%= f.check_box :workshop_id, id:"workshop_id" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>  
  <div class="actions col m6 s12">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit "Save", class:"btn green"%> 
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried with and without the  **id**  and **for**  attributes inside the input and the label, but nothing seems to work.
Am I missing something?

**EDIT 1**

The css that shows from Materialize css is the following:

```
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked), [type="checkbox"]:checked {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution, as simple as it is... Was to change the order of the `<input>` and the `<label>`

So instead of:

```
<%= f.label "#{workshop.name} \n\r #{workshop.date}", for:"workshop_id", id:"workshop_id" %>`
<%= f.check_box :workshop_id, id:"workshop_id" %>`
```

The righ way is:

```
<%= f.check_box :workshop_id, id:"workshop_id" %>
<%= f.label "#{workshop.name} \n\r #{workshop.date}", for:"workshop_id", id:"workshop_id" %>
```

Solved.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I realized I was using checkbox inside div with class "input-field" which was breaking it.

Do **NOT** put checkbox input field inside `<div class="input-field col s12 m3"></div>`

Comment: If I don't put checkbox in an input-field div then it doesn't get properly aligned vertically with other inputs in the same row. And no, it's not breaking (at least my) checkboxes. In your case it is probably a combination of factors, not the direct usage of input-field wrapper.

Answer (score 4):

Same problem with a checkbox and materialize css. This worked for me..

```
<%= f.check_box :online %>
<%= f.label 'online', id:'online' %>
```

Answer (score 3):

This work for me:

```html
<div class="input-field col s3">
  <label>
    <%= form.check_box :main, id:"main" %>
    <span>Principal?</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@alishersadikov/materializecss-upgrade-dbe789197411 has more details

Comment: This seems like the only solution to work at the moment with the new version of MaterializeCSS

Answer (score 0):

Update for the current (as of the time of writing) MaterializeCSSS. In the times of MaterializeCSS pre-v1.0 (or pre-v0.100) one could simply put (HAML syntax, ERB needs the same)

```
= f.collection_check_boxes :mymodel_ids, Mymodel.all, :id, :description
```

and have a nicely laid out set of collection check boxes out of that single line. Since v1.0.0 (or 0.100.x – don't remember exactly when the straightforward checkboxes usage was ruined) to get the same result one needs to do:

```
= f.collection_check_boxes(:mymodel_ids, Mymodel.all, :id, :description) do |builder|
    %div
        = builder.label do
            = builder.check_box
            %span
                = builder.text
```

Similar with single checkboxes:

```
= address_fields.check_box :_destroy
= address_fields.label :_destroy, "#{t'users.edit.destroy'}"
```

becomes

```
= address_fields.label :_destroy do
    = address_fields.check_box :_destroy
    %span
        = "#{t'users.edit.destroy'}"
```

In case someone finds this question when looking for broken checkboxes after updating to V1.0